# SELECT row with Same Value in one Field but different value in another respective field

Tags: sql

I have a  query

```
SELECT clientcode, 
       branchcode, 
       maincode, 
       name, 
       actype, 
       cycode 
FROM   Master 
WHERE  name IN (SELECT name 
                FROM   Master 
                GROUP  BY name 
                HAVING Count(name) > 1) 
       AND isblocked <> 'C' 
       AND actype < '4E' 
ORDER  BY branchcode, 
          name, 
          actype, 
          cycode
```

Now I need to select the row from output of above query where Name is Same but ClientCode is different.

For Eg, two row have same name, suppose 'BISHNU BHANDARI' but they should have different clinetCode like '123' for one and '444' for another.

Comment: Pls share your actual data & desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add one additional clause in the `having` section:

```
SELECT clientcode, 
       branchcode, 
       maincode, 
       name, 
       actype, 
       cycode 
FROM   Master 
WHERE  name IN (SELECT name 
                FROM   Master 
                GROUP  BY name 
                HAVING Count(name) > 1
                and min (clientcode) != max (clientcode)) 
       AND isblocked <> 'C' 
       AND actype < '4E' 
ORDER  BY branchcode, 
          name, 
          actype, 
          cycode
```

This might not work if the clientcode is nullable and you want null to meet the inequality condition, but that would be easy enough to add in.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT min(clientcode), max(clientcode), count(distinct clientcode), 
       branchcode, 
       maincode, 
       name, 
       actype, 
       cycode 
FROM   master 
WHERE  name IN (SELECT name 
                FROM   master 
                GROUP  BY name 
                HAVING Count(name) > 1) 
       AND isblocked <> 'C' 
       AND actype < '4E' 
group by        branchcode, 
       maincode, 
       name, 
       actype, 
       cycode 
having 1 < count(distinct clientcode)
order by        branchcode, 
       maincode, 
       name, 
       actype, 
       cycode
```

if names belong to different branchcodes, etc
you have to remove these fields from "group by" and select them aggregated like I did with clientcode above